# Ninja Forms : Display Checkbox List and File Upload Value in PDF Submission

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display checkbox list and file upload value in my pdf template.
The code for all regular fields works perfectly :

```
<?php echo $fields[‘fieldkeyexample’][value];?>
```

For checkbox list and file upload the same code shows only text “Array” in my pdf.
Can someone tell me the right way of doing it so it displays selected options in the PDF?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the way for the both :

`<?php echo implode($fields['file_upload_1553525572283']['value']);?>`